# What loader does googleapi need?

Tags: webpack, google-api, serverless-framework

I am writing a serverless application using googleapi

```
// in my ./api/google.js
import { google } from "googleapis"
...
...
```

When I try to build the project (using `serverless deploy`), the following error appeared.
Note: before adding the ./api/google.js file, my project build properly

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (101:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| async function fastFailMetadataRequest(options) {
|     const secondaryOptions = {
|         ...options,
|         url: options.url.replace(getBaseUrl(), getBaseUrl(exports.SECONDARY_HOST_ADDRESS)),
|     };
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/envDetect.js 17:20-43
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js
 @ ./apis/google.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (75:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }
|         const header = this.keyId
|             ? { ...DEFAULT_HEADER, kid: this.keyId }
|             : DEFAULT_HEADER;
|         const payload = Object.assign(defaultClaims, additionalClaims);
 @ ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js 27:18-45
 @ ./node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js
 @ ./apis/google.js
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Webpack compilation error, see above
  ...
  ...
```

What was the root cause for this error?

Comment: you have babel loader configured?

Comment: I used a serverless (sls) template and I did not change anything